# Node JS Not returning the Result

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

Here is my code. When I send the request, I'm not getting the result back. I didn't understand why it is not working in case 1. I modified it a little bit and put that inside **then**, and it is working.

What I'm doing wrong here?
Why it is not working in Case 1?
How to make it work in case 1 with out using res.end() like case 3.

**Case 1:**

```
var vigeonCollector = function(req, res) {

// console.log(req.body);
try {
    var store = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body).toString('utf8').replace("'",'"'));
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("Error in JSON Parsing!");
    return res.status(422).json({"status":false, "message":"Unparsble JSON"});
}

var payloads = [];

store.timestamp = getTimeStamp(); // Should be tagged with current timestamp.

// Adding event_day IST and UTC format.
var currentUTCTime = new Date();
var currentISTTime = new Date(currentUTCTime.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }));
store.event_day = currentUTCTime.toLocaleString().split(',')[0];
store.event_day_ist = currentISTTime.toLocaleString().split(',')[0];
store.advertiser_id_met = store.advertiser_id;
store.device_id_met = store.device_id;


// Call get on redis only once and use it for attribution.
var redis_result;
redis.get(store.device_id).then(function(jresult){
    redis_result = JSON.parse(jresult);
    console.log(redis_result);
    if (store.event_type == "UNINSTALLS") {

        // Attributing user installed UTM Params.
        store.event_properties.utm_medium = redis_result.user_installed_medium;
        store.event_properties.utm_source = redis_result.user_installed_source;
        store.event_properties.utm_campaign = redis_result.user_installed_campaign;
        store.advertiser_id = redis_result.advertiser_id;

    }
    else {

        // Tagging last user session UTM Params.
        store.event_properties.utm_medium = redis_result.medium;
        store.event_properties.utm_source = redis_result.source;
        store.event_properties.utm_campaign = redis_result.campaign;

    }

    temp_obj = { topic: "vnk-clst", messages: JSON.stringify(store)};
    payloads.push(temp_obj);
    console.log(payloads);
    console.log("I'm Done!");

});

producer.send(payloads, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
    if (err) return res.status(503).json({ "status": false, "message": "503 Service Unavailable", "error": err });
    else return res.status(200).json({ "status": true, "message": "OK"});
});
```

}

**Case 2:**

```
var vigeonCollector = function(req, res) {

// console.log(req.body);
try {
    var store = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body).toString('utf8').replace("'",'"'));
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("Error in JSON Parsing!");
    return res.status(422).json({"status":false, "message":"Unparsble JSON"});
}

var payloads = [];

store.timestamp = getTimeStamp(); // Should be tagged with current timestamp.

// Adding event_day IST and UTC format.
var currentUTCTime = new Date();
var currentISTTime = new Date(currentUTCTime.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }));
store.event_day = currentUTCTime.toLocaleString().split(',')[0];
store.event_day_ist = currentISTTime.toLocaleString().split(',')[0];
store.advertiser_id_met = store.advertiser_id;
store.device_id_met = store.device_id;


// Call get on redis only once and use it for attribution.
var redis_result;
redis.get(store.device_id).then(function(jresult){
    redis_result = JSON.parse(jresult);
    console.log(redis_result);
    if (store.event_type == "UNINSTALLS") {

        // Attributing user installed UTM Params.
        store.event_properties.utm_medium = redis_result.user_installed_medium;
        store.event_properties.utm_source = redis_result.user_installed_source;
        store.event_properties.utm_campaign = redis_result.user_installed_campaign;
        store.advertiser_id = redis_result.advertiser_id;

    }
    else {

        // Tagging last user session UTM Params.
        store.event_properties.utm_medium = redis_result.medium;
        store.event_properties.utm_source = redis_result.source;
        store.event_properties.utm_campaign = redis_result.campaign;

    }

    temp_obj = { topic: "vnk-clst", messages: JSON.stringify(store)};
    payloads.push(temp_obj);
    console.log(payloads);
    console.log("I'm Done!");

producer.send(payloads, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
    if (err) return res.status(503).json({ "status": false, "message": "503 Service Unavailable", "error": err });
    else return res.status(200).json({ "status": true, "message": "OK"});
});

});

}
```

**Case 3:**  Adding res.end() just before the last }.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `then` in case 1 directly does not wait until all of your code within the function you gave to it has finished. So the call to `producer.send(...)` starts too early before you filled your payload. The right way is to include the `producer.send(...)` into the function you gave to `then()`. The call to `res.end()` shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But if you see https://github.com/Gowtham95india/CapVengine/blob/master/server.js statsCollector function in which I'm calling producer.send is working fine. Is it because forEach loop delaying the call and Object is pushed?

And you said, producer.send starts too early, if it is the case, it should return 200. Isn't ? as I'm returning 200 in producer.send function and it doesn't matter even if I send empty payload, kafka returns true. 

Could you please explain this?

Comment: The implementation of `statsCollector()` is very fragile and there is no guarantee that your `payloads` structure is completly filled before you hand it to `producer.send()`.

Comment: Do you understand the concept behind Promises in Javascript? They "live" behind the `then()` function etc.....

Comment: If you add a log statement in case 1 right before `producer.send(...)` then i think you will see it's output before your "I'm Done!" output. And do you see the output of your `console.log(data);` call?

Comment: Thanks Marc,  I'm new to NodeJS. I'm really not so clear about promises in js. Could you please suggest the best way to send all the payloads to producer in statsCollector()?

Comment: I would use good promise library like Bluebird (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html). You then can use something like `Promise.all([.. here all your promises..]).then(function(all_results_array) {...})`. It takes an array of promises. And you append by `then` a function that gets called with all results in an array after *all* promised have settled.

Comment: I tried a draft version for your problem here: https://gist.github.com/snrmwg/eb3cc248cba83fccfb2de15b0f0c2937

Comment: no, before I'm done. there is no record of console.(data)